# how to upload to cloudinary using vue composition api

Tags: vuejs3

how to change this options api code to composition api the code try to upload photo to cloudinary and i found this code on cloudinary documenttion but i want to use composition api is thier any one who can help me change it

```
<template>
  <div class="cl-upload">
    <!-- supply h2 heading -->
    <h2>Upload an Image to Cloudinary</h2>
    <div v-show="showProgress">
      <progress-bar :options="options" :value="progress" />
    </div>

    <!-- create a form that will not submit to a server but will prevent submit and
    use the upload function as a handle-->
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="upload">
      <!-- bind cloud-name to the input -->
      <label for="cloudname-input">Cloud Name:</label>
      <input id="cloudname-input" v-model="cloudName" placeholder="Enter cloud_name from dashboard" />
      <!-- bind preset to the input -->
      <label for="preset-input">Preset:</label>
      <input id="preset-input" v-model="preset" placeholder="Enter preset from upload settings" />
      <!-- allow the user to select an image file and when they have selected it call a function 
      to handle this event-->
      <label for="file-input">Upload:</label>
      <input
        id="file-input"
        type="file"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        @change="handleFileChange($event)"
      />
      <!-- submit button is disabled until a file is selected -->
      <button type="submit" :disabled="filesSelected < 1">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <!-- display uploaded image if successful -->
    <section v-if="results && results.secure_url">
      <img :src="results.secure_url" :alt="results.public_id" />
    </section>

    <!-- display errors if not successful -->
    <section>
      <ul v-if="errors.length > 0">
        <li v-for="(error,index) in errors" :key="index">{{error}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import ProgressBar from "vuejs-progress-bar";
export default {
  name: "CloudinaryUpload",
  components: {
    ProgressBar
  },
  data() {
    const progressBarOptions = {
      text: {
        shadowColor: "black",
        fontSize: 14,
        fontFamily: "Helvetica",
        dynamicPosition: true
      },
      progress: {
        color: "#E8C401",
        backgroundColor: "#000000"
      },
      layout: {
        height: 35,
        width: 140,
        type: "line",
        progressPadding: 0,
        verticalTextAlign: 63
      }
    };
    return {
      results: null,
      errors: [],
      file: null,
      filesSelected: 0,
      cloudName: "",
      preset: "",
      tags: "browser-upload",
      progress: 0,
      showProgress: false,
      options: progressBarOptions,
      fileContents: null,
      formData: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // function to handle file info obtained from local
    // file system and set the file state
    handleFileChange: function(event) {
      console.log("handlefilechange", event.target.files);
      //returns an array of files even though multiple not used
      this.file = event.target.files[0];
      this.filesSelected = event.target.files.length;
    },
    prepareFormData: function() {
      this.formData = new FormData();
      this.formData.append("upload_preset", this.preset);
      this.formData.append("tags", this.tags); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
      this.formData.append("file", this.fileContents);
    },
    // function to handle form submit
    upload: function() {
      //no need to look at selected files if there is no cloudname or preset
      if (this.preset.length < 1 || this.cloudName.length < 1) {
        this.errors.push("You must enter a cloud name and preset to upload");
        return;
      }
      // clear errors
      else {
        this.errors = [];
      }
      console.log("upload", this.file.name);

      let reader = new FileReader();
      // attach listener to be called when data from file
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function() {
          this.fileContents = reader.result;
          this.prepareFormData();
          let cloudinaryUploadURL = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${this.cloudName}/upload`;
          let requestObj = {
            url: cloudinaryUploadURL,
            method: "POST",
            data: this.formData,
            onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
              console.log("progress", progressEvent);
              this.progress = Math.round(
                (progressEvent.loaded * 100.0) / progressEvent.total
              );
              console.log(this.progress);
            //bind "this" to access vue state during callback
            }.bind(this)
          };
          //show progress bar at beginning of post
          this.showProgress = true;
          axios(requestObj)
            .then(response => {
              this.results = response.data;
              console.log(this.results);
              console.log("public_id", this.results.public_id);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.errors.push(error);
              console.log(this.error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
              setTimeout(
                function() {
                  this.showProgress = false;
                }.bind(this),
                1000
              );
            });
        }.bind(this),
        false
      );
      // call for file read if there is a file
      if (this.file && this.file.name) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

help me change or give me a guide to upload to cloadinary and get back the url for further use

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could quickly come up with.

In Vuejs 3 you need to use refs or reactive for mutable data inside your components.I used refs in this case, you can use reactive depending on your use case. Methods are converted to plain functions in Vuejs 3 composition-api.

For a more complete guide on Vuejs 3 migration check this out [Vue 3 Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/) from the Vuejs team.
NOTE: I havent tested this code.

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import ProgressBar from "vuejs-progress-bar";

const results = ref(null);
const errors = ref([]);
const file = ref();
const filesSelected = ref(0);
const cloudName = ref("");
const preset = ref("");
const tags = ref("browser-upload");
const progress = ref(0);
const showProgress = ref(false);
const options = ref(progressBarOptions);
const fileContents = ref(null);
const formData = ref();
const progressBarOptions = ref({
  text: {
    shadowColor: "black",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    dynamicPosition: true
  },
  progress: {
    color: "#E8C401",
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  },
  layout: {
    height: 35,
    width: 140,
    type: "line",
    progressPadding: 0,
    verticalTextAlign: 63
  }
});

function handleFileChange(event) {
  console.log("handlefilechange", event.target.files);
  file.value = event.target.files[0];
  filesSelected.value = event.target.files.length;
}

function prepareFormData() {
  formData.value = new FormData();
  formData.value.append("upload_preset", preset.value);
  formData.value.append("tags", tags.value);
  formData.value.append("file", fileContents.value);
}

function upload() {
  if (preset.value.length < 1 || cloudName.value.length < 1) {
    errors.value.push("You must enter a cloud name and preset to upload");
    return;
  } else {
    errors.value = [];
  }
  console.log("upload", file.value.name);

  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function() {
      fileContents.value = reader.result;
      prepareFormData();
      let cloudinaryUploadURL = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName.value}/upload`;
      let requestObj = {
        url: cloudinaryUploadURL,
        method: "POST",
        data: formData.value,
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
          console.log("progress", progressEvent);
          progress.value = Math.round(
            (progressEvent.loaded * 100.0) / progressEvent.total
          );
          console.log(progress.value);
        }.bind(this)
      };

      showProgress.value = true;
      axios(requestObj)
        .then((response) => {
          results.value = response.data;
          console.log(results.value);
          console.log("public_id", results.value.public_id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          errors.value.push(error.value);
          console.log(error.value);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setTimeout(
            function() {
              showProgress.value = false;
            }.bind(this),
            1000
          );
        });
    }.bind(this),
    false
  );

  if (file.value && file.value.name) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.value);
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="cl-upload">
    <h2>Upload an Image to Cloudinary</h2>
    <div v-show="showProgress">
      <progress-bar :options="options" :value="progress" />
    </div>

    <form v-on:submit.prevent="upload">
      <label for="cloudname-input">Cloud Name:</label>
      <input id="cloudname-input" v-model="cloudName" placeholder="Enter cloud_name from dashboard" />

      <label for="preset-input">Preset:</label>
      <input id="preset-input" v-model="preset" placeholder="Enter preset from upload settings" />

      <label for="file-input">Upload:</label>
      <input
        id="file-input"
        type="file"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        @change="handleFileChange($event)"
      />

      <button type="submit" :disabled="filesSelected < 1">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <section v-if="results && results.secure_url">
      <img :src="results.secure_url" :alt="results.public_id" />
    </section>

    <section>
      <ul v-if="errors.length > 0">
        <li v-for="(error, index) in errors" :key="index">{{ error }}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: brother thank you for your help but i am not familiar with typescript so if you can do it in pure vue js that will be helpfull